# How to return array unique value? in php

Tags: php

I need an array like this in PHP?

```
array = [mani , mani, nithi, nithi, basto]

return in 

array = [basto] 

not for other elements
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Turn that into PHP code and what's the problem? https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: are you looking for quotese/double quotes to make php able to understand than your array contains strings ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$items = ['mani' , 'mani', 'nithi', 'nithi', 'basto'];

$counts   = array_count_values($items);
// Remove elements that occur more than once.
$filtered = array_filter($items, function ($item) use ($counts) {
    return $counts[$item] === 1;
});

var_export($filtered);
```

Output:

```
array (
    4 => 'basto',
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to specify your question so users here can provide better assistance.

To your issue:

`array_unique($array);`

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

**EDIT:** you want to search all items by name, to do that you need this function: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

with your example:

```
$array = ['mani' , 'mani', 'nithi', 'nithi', 'basto'];
$basto = array_search('basto', $array);
```

Best,
Sebo

Comment: thanks, i need only basto element not for other elements

Comment: ah I understand. You want basto return from your array. I updated my answer with array_search function - see above.